# How to implement a conditional fomula in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a table named tblRecovery with 4 column. ID, LStatus, Amount and RecoveredBy I created a formula to sum Amount Column where LStatus Column value is "WCL". I use following code.

It sum all value of Amount column without condition. I want to sum amount column if Lstatus Column value is "WCL". How can I do that?

```
if {tblRecovery.LStatus}='WCL' then sum({tblRecovery.Amount})
```

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports formulas work on a per-record basis.

Your current formula shows the sum of `tblRecovery.Amount` on every single row where `LStatus='WCL'`.

To get the desired result, create a formula-field with following formula and the create a sum of it:

```
if {tblRecovery.LStatus}='WCL' then
    {tblRecovery.Amount}
else
    0
```